# In playstore, How to parse the version value that appears after the button is clicked

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I'm using jsoup library

I trying to get version number of my application

(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keehl.laromacorea)

The html structure of the playstore changes periodically.

So I have to change the my source code periodically.

I resolve the problem currently.

But this time I can't get version number.

Now, the application's version number appeared after click the arrow button next to the application information text.

So, The application's version number is not existed in the html text before the click the button.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

if u want available current version on google play store

i did it once in my app like this:

create new Class

```
public class GooglePlayVersionChecker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private String availableVersion;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        availableVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "&hl=en")
                .timeout(30000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get()
                .select("div.hAyfc:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")
                .first()
                .ownText();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return availableVersion;
}
```

}

and then you can call it like:

```
public String readVersionNumberAvailable(){
        GooglePlayVersionChecker versionChecker = new GooglePlayVersionChecker();
        try {
            googlePlayVersion = versionChecker.execute().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return googlePlayVersion;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but its not working...